Why does the positive semidefinite matrix define a half space?
It was said that the positive semidefinite (PSD) matrix define a half space like in this lecture (see the bottom of the pp.1) and in the convex optimization book by Stephen Boyd$^1$. Although I have found an answer that vectorize the PSD matrix to form a half space in n-dimensional vector space, it doesn't seem to prove that PSD matrix define a half space, where PSD matrix in $\mathbf{S}^n$ is seen as a free vector ( $\mathbf{S}^n$ denotes the set of symmetric $n \times n$ matrices,). Could anyone help me with it or did I misunderstand anything there?

$^1$Convex Optimization by Boyd & Vandenberghe, pp.36

I am not exactly sure what you are asking. For any fixed $x$, the set ${ A \in \mathbb{S}^n  | x^T A x \ge 0 }$ is a half space. Note that $f_x(A) = x^T Ax$ is a linear functional.

@copper.hat Sorry for not presenting my problem clearly. I think my question is why ${ A \in \mathbb{S}^n  | x^T A x \ge 0 }$ is a half space. As the definition that I know is related to the dot product and I can easily see why it's a "half space" in Euclidean space. But for the PSD matrix, I don't really figure it out why it's a half space and whether I can visualize it to help me understand it.

It is a half space of symmetric matrices, I'm not sure where you are getting a psd matrix from. The half space will contain psd matrices, but will have many others too.

Thanks for the reply. Yes, the psd will be just a subset of it.  I think I get what you mean by it's a half space of symmetric matrices. Maybe I can compare it to the half space in Euclidean space, where both of them are linear functional and greater or less than a number?

It is a half space in Euclidean space.

Could you elaborate a little bit more here? For a half space in Euclidean space, I will think of something like ${\mathbf{x} \mid \mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x} \leq b}$, where $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}$, but when symmetric matrix is seen as a vector I don't know how it still can define a half space in Euclidean space. Sorry my question might be silly.

You would have to be more specific about what is bothering you. In general, a half space is defined by some continuous linear functional $f$ as the set of points satisfying $f(x) \ge 0$ (or $\le 0, <0, >0$, of course). For a fixed $x$, the mapping $A \mapsto x^TAx$ is a continuous linear functional. Another approach is to define the (Frobenius) inner product between two matrices as $\langle A, B \rangle = \operatorname{tr} (A^TB) = \sum_{i,j} A_{ij} B_{ij}$, and then the halfspace can be written as ${ A \in \mathbb{S}^n | \langle xx^T, A \rangle \ge 0 }$.

I think I totally get it now, really thanks.
